# [antd]: Why is dynamically generated two-dimensional code blank?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I use the QRcode react&typescript plugin.
What I want to do is to pass an ID when the mouse moves up, and then dynamically generate a two-dimensional code, but I don't know why the two-dimensional code generated by canvas is blank and can be printed out in console, but the canvas inside is blank.

```
public mouseEnter = (e: any, index: number) => {
const id = e.target.getAttribute("data-activeid");
console.log(id);
qrCode
  .toCanvas("some url?id=" + id, { errorCorrectionLevel: "M" })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    this.setState({
      ell: res
    });
  });
};
```

code snippet：[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/536pnlq60n?module=%2Fsrc%2FQRcode.tsx)

Thank you.